# Uploading new Build under same version through error in Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am facing a weird error. I have uploaded app multiple times but getting a weird error.

Below is the screenshot the TestFlight

[image]

I have uploaded a new build of 1.1 under version 2.4 & its on Testflight.

Now If I tried to upload build number 1.2 under the same Version I am getting below error

[image]

I have cleaned my project, restarted Xcode but still getting the same error.

Please help me what am I doing wrong here. Any idea would be great.

Comment: what's your ready for sale version

Comment: its version 2.4 with build number 1.0

Comment: The error says that you must increase the 2.4 version number. This is obviously because your 2.4 version is live and if you upload a new build it will be a new release.. so version number needs to increase

Comment: ok..why build number 1.1 approved under same version 2.4

Comment: App version must increase per release. you cannot release a new version of the app with an existing version number? when did you do build 1.1? I doubt it would be approved if live version exists with same build number

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have some connectivity problem at your end. I suggest you to try again in a while. Apple servers are known to make fancy errors once in a while.

By the way, every time you do an upload, you can keep the version as it is but you should always update the build. But keep in mind that the new app version should be always higher than the ready for sale build's version number. To keep things clean and simple, I use simple integers and then increment it by one with each upload. The build number is not shown to the end users, so nothing to worry.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Apple documentation:

> CFBundleVersion (String - iOS, macOS) specifies the build version
> number of the bundle, which identifies an iteration (released or
> unreleased) of the bundle.
>
> The build version number should be a string comprised of three
> non-negative, period-separated integers with the first integer being
> greater than zero—for example, 3.1.2. The string should only contain
> numeric (0-9) and period (.) characters. Leading zeros are truncated
> from each integer and will be ignored (that is, 1.02.3 is equivalent
> to 1.2.3). The meaning of each element is as follows:
>
> The first number represents the most recent major release and is
> limited to a maximum length of four digits. The second number
> represents the most recent significant revision and is limited to a
> maximum length of two digits. The third number represents the most
> recent minor bug fix and is limited to a maximum length of two digits.
> If the value of the third number is 0, you can omit it and the second
> period.
>
> While developing a new version of your app, you can include a suffix
> after the number that is being updated; for example 3.1.3a1. The
> character in the suffix represents the stage of development for the
> new version. For example, you can represent development, alpha, beta,
> and final candidate, by d, a, b, and fc. The final number in the
> suffix is the build version, which cannot be 0 and cannot exceed 255.
> When you release the new version of your app, remove the suffix.

> CFBundleShortVersionString (String - iOS, macOS) specifies the release
> version number of the bundle, which identifies a released iteration of
> the app.
>
> The release version number is a string composed of three
> period-separated integers. The first integer represents major revision
> to the app, such as a revision that implements new features or major
> changes. The second integer denotes a revision that implements less
> prominent features. The third integer represents a maintenance release
> revision.
>
> The value for this key differs from the value for CFBundleVersion,
> which identifies an iteration (released or unreleased) of the app.
>
> This key can be localized by including it in your InfoPlist.strings
> files.
>
> See also NSHumanReadableCopyright.

So basically it is telling you that you have 1.1 version with already a 2.4, just increase at 2.5 at it should fix the issue.
I usually use a script that automatically increment the release version (build) using a UNIX timestamp.